# How to play ultrasonic WAV/PCM file in javascript without losing data

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, wav, pcm

I need to loop an audio file (WAV, OGG or raw PCM) in the browser that contains segments which are unheard (ultrasonic) by the human ear (yet contain data which is valuable to me).

Using Chrome on Mac, I've noticed that if the segments of unheard sound are relatively short, I get all the data back (heard + unheard). In contrast, if the segments of unheard sound are longer than a certain threshold, it will fade out the whole channel quickly and effectively cancel the rest of the file completely, until the next loop cycle begins.

The way I'm loading and playing the sound is like so:

```
var b = msg.data; // binary msg received from websocket
b.type = "audio/wav";
var URLObject = window.webkitURL || window.URL;
var url = URLObject.createObjectURL(b);
var snd = document.createElement("audio");
snd.setAttribute("src", url);
snd.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
    snd.loop = true;
    snd.muted = false;
    snd.play();
});
```

I'm looking for a way to cancel this automatic filtering of unheard sounds. Eventually, I would like a way to do this cross-browser. If not possible using JavaScript, a Flash solution will also be accepted.

Sample ultrasonic WAV files (~1MB each):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5sMkxczD6sNbm04MmxMTmIwdlk/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5sMkxczD6sNal91WUhRNWo2d3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Any way you can post a sample WAV?

Comment: Here's a link to a sample WAV on my google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5sMkxczD6sNal91WUhRNWo2d3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How do tell it is not playing? I can see the audio in the EQ meters of a sound app, but I can't tell if it is playing on a browser because obviously I can't hear it.

Comment: Your code snd.setAttribute("src", src), where is src set? what is the value for it?

Comment: You will need to capture it while playing with a software that can show you the waveform later. Playing in Chrome the captured waveform looks like it fades out quickly to nothing.

Comment: src should be url, fixed code. Also clarified 'mime' and 'msg.data'.

Comment: A complete guess, but perhaps the <audio> tag by default has a filter on it. Have you tried creating the audio using the AudioContext API? Like shown here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Comment: Looks like some browsers filter out "what you can't hear", have you looked at this in flash http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-play-external-wav-files-in-as3--active-8744 ? I don't have flash installed so can't test.

Comment: @AndrewPorritt thanks for the pointer. I'll try that later today.

Comment: @silver I actually have it working in Flash already, but since Flash doesn't work on iOS I would like to know if it's even possible in JS.

Comment: @AndrewPorritt according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext - AudioContext is not supported in IE, and unknown if works in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a single approach that will work on all browsers, unfortunately.
For most browsers on the desktop and iOS too you can use the Web Audio API as shown here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

For IE/Android you need to use Flash to play a WAV/PCM, or play OGG with HTML5 Audio tag, but the latter may lose the ultrasonic frequencies.

So in general, you need to write code that will check what the current browser supports and use that, starting with Web Audio API, then trying HTML5 Audio, then Flash.